# SQL Like vs. = Function Differently Without Wildcards

Tags: mysql, sql-like

I have a query where changing from `like` to `=` results in a match. My understanding was the `=` and `like` functioned the same unless wildcards were present. Neither `_` nor `%` are in my string. Characters present in my string are:

```
acdeijknoprtuy4@-.
```

My query was:

```
SELECT * FROM UserEmails WHERE email like ?
```

which returned 0 results, I changed it to:

```
SELECT * FROM UserEmails WHERE email = ?
```

and I got the 1 expected result returned. This is running on percona version of mysql 5.6.41.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string, or matching database value, most likely have trailing spaces.

See documentation for [MySQL 5.6](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/char.html):

> All MySQL collations are of type PAD SPACE. This means that all CHAR,
>   VARCHAR, and TEXT values are compared without regard to any trailing
>   spaces. “Comparison” in this context does not include the LIKE
>   pattern-matching operator, for which trailing spaces are significant.

[In MySQL 8.0](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/char.html):

> Most MySQL collations have a pad attribute of PAD SPACE. The
>   exceptions are Unicode collations based on UCA 9.0.0 and higher, which
>   have a pad attribute of NO PAD.

Comment: 'p' != '.'. Check directly from the database, not from application: `select email from UserEmails where email like '% '`. If you still have problems, create a SQLFiddle with sample data.